# Math.floor is returning NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

In Chrome this works fine but in IE and Firefox I get returned NaN. Any help is welcome.

Basically this is supposed to be a simple days countdown function. If I am also doing that wrong please let me know.

```js
var start_date = "09 Sep 16";

var end = new Date(start_date); // set expiry date and time..

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour *24
var timer;

function showRemaining()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {
       // handle expiry here..
       clearInterval( timer ); // stop the timer from continuing ..
       alert('Expired'); // alert a message that the timer has expired..

       return; // break out of the function so that we do not update the counters with negative values..
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = ' ' + days + ' ';

}
timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

```html
Count down: <div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: Where do you actually call `showRemaining()`?

Comment: Open your debugger and place a breakpoint before the `Math.floor()`.  What are the values of `distance` and `_day`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to copy in the setInterval

Answer (score 4):

From my console:

```
> new Date("09 Sep 16")
< [date] Invalid Date
```

Any math operations involving an invalid date will result in NaN.

You should either use the [ISO-8601 date format](https://xkcd.com/1179/) to specify the date (so `new Date("2016-09-09")`) or use the non-string-parsing version (`new Date(2016,8,9)`)

Comment: This worked for me. I had to update the date format being passed in. I guess it NEEDED to have a time associated with it to work in Firefox / IE. Chrome must give it a default time. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This is what firefox shows:
That is the reason Math.floor gives NaN

[image]